# How to create multiple buttons at runtime? + android

Tags: android

I wrote the following code but am not getting how to write `OnclickListner()` method for all buttons.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll1Relative);
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText(""+ i);
        b.setId(100+i);
        b.setWidth(30);
        b.setHeight(20);
        layout.addView(b, p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an anonymous inner method like this:

```
Button b = new Button(this);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
    }
});
b.setText("" + i);
b.setTag("button" + i);
b.setWidth(30);
b.setHeight(20);
```

Comment: The thing is i want to write SQLite query for each of the buttons separately.Is it better to use swith case? There are 10 buttons and each has separate query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the buttons to do different things, you could have your Activity extend OnClickListener, set `b.setOnClickListener(this)` in the loop, and add something like

```
@Override
public onClick(View v)
{
  // get who called by
  String sTag = (String) v.getTag();

  if (sTag.equals("button1"))
  {
    //do some stuff  
  }
  else if (sTag.equals("button2"))
  {
    //do some other stuff
  }
  // and so on
}
```

to handle the clicks.

---

And I'm editing this in here because the lack of line breaks makes comments ambiguous:

```
int iBtnID = v.getId(); 
switch (iBtnID) 
{
  case 101: 
    // do stuff; 
    break; 
  case 102: 
    // do other stuff 
    break; 
  // and so on 
}
```

Comment: insted of tag i am using setId(),will u please explain with switch case statment.

Comment: @Pramod : Edited switch/case into my previous answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

Button b1 = new Button(this);


b1.setText("Btn");
b1.setId(int i=2);
b1.setonClicklistenor(this);
lin .addView(b1);
```

and

```
onclick (View v){


int i=v.getId();

if (i==2){

///operation
}
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The problem the OP had was how to handle the click events for the buttons.