# How to construct a button on runtime (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-button

There's nothing on this particular feature of Android in the documentation (for example here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html#Button(android.content.Context)

How do i add a button to exsiting layout (or create a layout on runtime as well)?

And then, how do i apply attributes to said button i've just created?

Comment: Did you read this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763366/how-to-create-multiple-buttons-at-runtime-android

Comment: Is Google down where you are?  Hundreds of hits when I try.

Comment: The search function is your friend!

Comment: Okay you are right i didn't search too well, sorry for creating so-called 'useless' question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create button from code. you can find all the alternative methods of setting attribute in the doc. for  example

```
          Button button = new Button(this); 
          button.setText("hi"); 
          button.setId(Id);
          button.setTextColor(Color.Red);
          button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
          buttonlayout.addView(button);
```